# Chrome extension как закрыть все вкладки кроме активной?

Tags: jquery, chrome-extension, chrome-app

есть код для расширения который закрывает все вкладки браузера

```
chrome.tabs.query({}, function (tabs) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        chrome.tabs.remove(tabs[i].id);
    }
});
```

подскажите пожалуйста если кто то знает решение, как сделать что бы закрывались не чисто все вкладки, а все кроме активной вкладки?

Comment: у [таба](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab) есть свойство `active`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте свойство `active`:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: false}, function (tabs) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        chrome.tabs.remove(tabs[i].id);
    }
});
```

Все параметры функции `query` [тут](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query)

Comment: это на пример сделать так? chrome.tabs.query({}, function (tabs) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
 chrome.tabs.query({active: false}, function (tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.remove(tabs[i].id);
 });
    }
});